# Tabs, line breaks encoding when uploading PHP files on my server

Tags: php, ftp, notepad++

I am writing a PHP application and developing it localy (easyPHP). However, when I transfer my files on my server (FTP), i get on of the following error :

- Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /homez.93/dockydoc/_apps/dockydocs/include/functions.php on line xx
- Error unexpected error function on line 1
- Etc..;

When I re-download my PHP files and open them with Notepad++ or the classic windows pad, their are no more spaces, line break or tabulation in my file ! This result in the server not to be able to read PHP.

My files are UTF8 without BOM encoded (in Notepad++). I can't find the solution to this proble despite thorought search on the Internet... I anyone could help .. :)

Thanks,
Romain

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using ASCII mode data connection when uploading the files over FTP. If you are set to binary, I believe this causes this!

Comment: Thanks, i also thought is was something like this. I change the transfert type to ASCII but nohing's changed...